# Отразить часть строки

Tags: python

Есть строка, например: "abc23z18pK1", нужно чтобы получилось "abc18z13pK2", то есть поменялась последовательность цифр, при это чтобы буквы никак не изменялись. Я уже и через replace, и с помощью модуля re пытался, у меня не получается! И нужно не просто поменять местами, а именно <<отразить>> цифры, такое вот условие поставили мне. Можете подсказать как это можно реализовать с написанием не очень большого кода?

Comment: Прям огромного?

Comment: Ну если учесть код который пишу я, хоть он и не получается, он у меня растягивается на строк так 15-30

Comment: `"abc23z18pK1".replace("abc23", "abc18").replace("z18", "z13").replace("pK1", "pK2")`?

Comment: я так тоже пробовал, но сказали что нужно не заменить, одно число на другое, а именно <<отразить>>((((

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
s = 'abc23z18pK1'
it = iter([i for i in s if i.isdigit()][::-1])
mirrored = ''.join(next(it) if c.isdigit() else c for c in s)
print(mirrored)  # abc18z13pK2
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот пока что я придумал

```
word = "abc23z18pK1"
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
rotated = []
result = ""

for i in word:
    if i in numbers:
        rotated.append(i)

rotated.reverse()
it = 0
for i in word:

    if i in numbers:
        result += rotated[it]
        it += 1
    else:
        result += i

print(result)
```

> abc18z13pK2

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста в ответ результат

Comment: Да, конечно....

Comment: Кст, вот пример как в одну строку заполнить: `rotated = [i for i in word if i in '0123456789']` А условие `if i in '0123456789'` тоже самое что `if i.isdigit()`